# Function can't access Label

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine, label

I have two function that use a UIDocument Label

```
public class UIController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Label argentTexte;

    private int currentInt;
    private string currentString;

    void Start()
    {
        var root = GetComponent<UIDocument>().rootVisualElement;

        argentTexte = root.Q<Label>("currentMoney");
        Debug.Log(argentTexte.text); //<- show some string
    }

    public void IncreaseMoney(int moneyToAdd)
    {
        currentString = GetComponent<UIDocument>().rootVisualElement.Q<Label>("currentMoney").text; // Don't show anything, throw error
        Debug.Log(argentTexte.text); //throw an NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
        int.TryParse(currentString, out currentInt);
        argentTexte.text = $"{currentInt + moneyToAdd}";
    }
    
public void DecreaseMoney(int moneyToDecrease)
    {
        currentString = GetComponent<UIDocument>().rootVisualElement.Q<Label>("currentMoney").text; // show some string
        int.TryParse(currentString, out currentInt);
        argentTexte.text = $"{currentInt - moneyToDecrease}";
    }
}
```

`DecreaseMoney()` is used on an object when i spawn it and it work, `IncreaseMoney()` is used on a child of an object when its destroyed and doesn't work.

Why `DecreaseMoney()` have access to `argentTexte.text` and not `IncreaseMoney()` ?

Comment: Does it pick up the value in start? If so. Stop trying to find it every time. If not it would suggest something has destroyed it as there looks to be nothing else wrong

Comment: @SadlyFullStack the object is destroyed like so `
        {
            UI.IncreaseMoney(argent.argent);
            Destroy(transform.parent.gameObject);
        }`
@BugFinder it pick the value in `Start()` but i can't access it in `IncreaseMoney()`

Comment: `DecreaseMoney() is used on an object when i spawn it and it work, IncreaseMoney() is used on a child of an object when its destroyed and doesn't work.` If this is called after the according object has been destroyed then using `GetComponent` would return an already destroyed component .. so I don't know exactly how `UIDocument` works inside but it is totally possible that somewhere you try to access values that already have been reset/disposed etc ... It would help to know a little more details about how these methods are called exactly